# Как сделать переход между background-color двух divов

Tags: html, css, веб-дизайн, градиент

Нужно сделать плавный переход между двумя блоками, но не знаю как это можно реализовать.
[image]
с #C4C4C4 к #000000

Comment: сделайте этим двум блокам обёртку и задайте градиент для обёртки, а не для двух дивов

Answer (score 4):

Оно?

```css
.wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C4C4C4, #000000);
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>BLOCK 1</div>
  <div>BLOCK 2</div>
</div>
```